# Enabling RDP Access to HDInsight Cluster via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-powershell

I have created a HDInsight Cluster via PowerShell and have enabled the RDP Access to it by logging into Azure Management Portal. However, I wanted to know if it is possible to enable RDP Access to a HDInsight Cluster via PowerShell. If yes, please give some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current version of HDInsight does not offer alternatives to the portal to enable RDP.

Answer (score 2):

Use below command to create RDP enabled cluster.
Command to be used with  to be used with Azure ARM PowerShell, 1.0.1 or later – you can install Azure RM PS via web platform installer or follow this blog https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azps-1-0/ 
Provide values for -RdpAccessExpiry and -RdpCredential in the command.

New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster [-Location]  [-ResourceGroupName]  [-ClusterName]  [-ClusterSizeInNodes]  [-HttpCredential]  [[-DefaultStorageAccountName]  ] [[-DefaultStorageAccountKey]  ] [-AadTenantId  ] [-AdditionalStorageAccounts  ] [-SshCredential  ] [-SshPublicKey  ] [-SubnetName  ] [-Version  ] [-VirtualNetworkId  ] [-WorkerNodeSize  ] [-ZookeeperNodeSize  ] [ ]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about HDInsight instances, but this is now much simpler in VM instances, using the new Extensions:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wats/archive/2014/03/06/enable-rdp-or-reset-password-with-the-vm-agent.aspx

Example:

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName clmar4ws12r2b -Name clmar4ws12r2b | 
        Set-AzureVMAccessExtension | 
        Update-AzureVM
```